# Arch Linux Live USB no longer booting UEFI

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader, uefi

My Lenovo laptop is running Arch Linux with a UEFI GPT partition table. One day I powered up my laptop, but couldn't get passed the Lenovo boot screen. I used a USB stick to boot up and reinstall Arch. However after this I still couldn't get passed the Lenovo boot screen. I tried to reinstall it again using the same USB stick and ended up with two entries in my UEFI boot menu. I formatted the GUID partition to FAT32 using GPARTED live USB which deleted them. However I can no longer use my Arch UEFI USB stick to boot up. I get to the bootloader menu on the USB stick but after the timeout I get a blank screen.

Comment: side note: you don't have a UEFI-enabled BIOS. you either have a BIOS or you have UEFI.

Comment: also, you're going to have to be way more specific. how did you reinstall Arch? two entries in which boot menu, the USB drive or the hard drive? what do you mean you formatted the GUID back to FAT? do you mean the EFI system partition?

Comment: I was under the impression that the EFI system partition was just a FAT32 partition on the HDD. I haven't had the laptop long and I've not really played about with UEFI and its confusing me haha. I'll update my question now

Comment: yes, it is. but I don't understand what you mean by GUID partition - you should maybe do some reading on what a GUID is.

Comment: Sorry I meant the EFI System Partition.

Comment: try editing the bootloader commandline and remove "quiet" from the kernel parameters. also, try appending "systemd.default=rescue.target" to the end.

Comment: I've managed to boot up Ubuntu and Fedora live USB sticks with UEFI on the laptop so I think its an Arch problem. How do I do that? I followed this guide to make the USB stick in the first place. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Create_UEFI_bootable_USB_from_ISO Do I have to edit a file after I've followed those steps?

Comment: Or do I do that from the bootloder menu on the stick?

Comment: Press e at the GRUB menu on the stick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have faced with same problem. My laptop Lenovo X230 did not load in UEFI mode when I used Archlinux or Manjaro installation medias (I see black screen when image started to load). I googled and found that it is happened because Arch uses gummiboot loader.

You can fix this issue with next steps:

1. Make the bootable flash from the installation ISO;
2. From the other any PC with linux install GRUB2 to the flash drive:

   ```
   grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/sdc1/boot --efi-directory=/mnt/sdc1 --target=x86_64-efi --removable
   ```
3. I used next config for GRUB2 (/mnt/sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg, example for Manjaro linux):

   ```
   set timeout=5
   menuentry "MJRO_089" {
   linux /manjaro/boot/x86_64/manjaroiso root=LABEL=MJRO_089 rw
   initrd /manjaro/boot/x86_64/manjaro.img
   }
   ```

This instruction also useful for Archlinux.

Comment: can you explain what happens in steps 2 and 3?